# What does NaN mean when I'm testing an xpath function in CommCare App Preview

Tags: commcare

I'm adding several numbers in a hidden value, however I'm seeing the number return as NaN in the xpath tester in App Preview. What does NaN mean in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NaN means "Not a Number." This often happens when you're using a function that can only deal with numbers and there's a blank input in your calculation.